# 404 error when hit submit from php file for requested path E:\vise\jqproject\web\errorpages\403_error.htm

Tags: php, iis, http-status-code-404

I have a php script that when I hit submit, it submits the form to another php file with a get command.  This worked about a month ago, but this month it's having issues.  This is what the relevant code looks like in the table php file. Running table.php shows the table in the browser and has 404 errors when I hit submit.

table.php:

```
<body>  
    <h1> Visual Evaluation Entry Table </h1>
    <form method="get" action="visEupload.php">
<table id="bigTable" border="1">
    <thead>
     <tr>
       <!--<th id="bandY" class="col3">Bands @263mm Y</th><th id="bandM" class="col3">Bands @263mm M</th><th id="bandC" class="col3">Bands @263mm C</th><th id="bandK" class="col3">Bands @263mm K</th><th id="Comments" class="col3">Comments</th>-->
     <th id="bandY" class="col3">Bands @263mm Y</th><th id="bandM" class="col3">Bands @263mm M</th><th id="bandC" class="col3">Bands @263mm C</th><th id="bandK" class="col3">Bands @263mm K</th><th id="Comments" class="col3">Comments</th>
     </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr name="MCBands" id="9214">
            <!--<td><input name="Yevaluation" ></td>  //Row 0 Column 1-->
            <!--<td><input name="Mevaluation" ></td>  //Row 0 Column 2-->
            <!--<td><input name="Cevaluation" ></td>  //Row 0 Column 3-->
            <!--<td><input name="Kevaluation" ></td>  //Row 0 Column 4-->
            <!--<td><input name="comment" ></td>  //Row 0 Column 4-->
            <td><input name="bandY" ></td>  <!--//Row 0 Column 1-->
            <td><input name="bandM" ></td> <!-- //Row 0 Column 2-->
            <td><input name="bandC" ></td> <!-- //Row 0 Column 3-->
            <td><input name="bandK" ></td><!--  //Row 0 Column 4-->
            <td><input name="comment" ></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>

</table>
  <input id="submit" type="submit" class="list" name="submit" value="Submit To Database" >  

   <!--maybe move all php part to other file-->

   </form>
</body>
```

The server is mapped so when we run it off of the server, we use the server ip address and my file name and skip the rest of the path, which works fine with the table.php file, so that mapping appears correct.  When I run it off of the server (from my desk) and hit submit it gives me a 404 file or directory not found.  When I run it locally on the server, it's saying it can't find the file name, but it says the requested url is `http://localhost:80/errorpages/403_error.html.`  Physical path: E:\vise\jqproject\web\errorpages\403_error.html.  The error message says the notification is from the MapRequestHandler of Module IIS Web Core.

(Running on the server) When I change the action in the table.php get to include the IP address, it's behaving weirdly:
Module IIS Web Core Notification MapRequestHandler Handler PHP53_via_FastCGI, Requested URL `

```
http://localhost:80/13.141.xxx.xx/visEupload.php?bandy=xx&bandM=xx&bandc=hj&bandk=xx&comment=xx&submit=submit+to+database
```

physical path shows as E:\visE\jqproject\web\13.141.xxx.xx\visEupload.php 
Login Method and user Anonymous.

When I change the url to just be

```
localhost/viseUpload.php
```

it's getting HTTP Error 404 not found.  Any ideas why it's not finding the visEupload.php file?  It has the correct .php extension.  In file properties it's a type php file with name visEupload.php.

I took a look at [404 error](http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/bugs-issues-/server-error-404---file-or-directory-not-found) but I see my "allowUnlisted="true" in applicationHost.config. I'm not using sitefinity, though.  I'm not sure if something got over-written when we did a server windows update.

I know we were having a problem with get and post a couple months ago and we had to add them to the IIS Manager Handler Mappings somewhere, but don't remember where we added them to check.  Since I tried directly accessing the visEupload.php without any get (and commented out get code in the file) it should have worked if that was the issue.

We are running server 2008 R2 and I'm not sure which version of IIS it is.

In case it matters, this is the contents of the visEupload.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" >
<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" /> 
    <title>Big Table</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php 


    require_once( "../classes/class.OLAPdatabase.php");
    require_once( "../common/Session.php");
    $OLAPdb = new OLAPdatabase;


    /*

      handling of the get part is commented out
     */
   ?>
</body>
```

Comment: 403 is "forbidden", which usually means that somehow the URL you're hitting literally is forbidden for you to access. e.g. bad username/password will result in a 403. 404 is "not found" - the resource literally doesn't exist.

Comment: I lost track of what you tried and what the result of each one was, but `http//localhost:80/13....` is missing a `:` after `http` and `localhost/viseUpload.php` is missing the scheme `http://`, so if these aren't copy/paste errors you would get odd results for those.

Comment: I  added the ":" as you noticed I was missing/typo above.

Comment: @MarcB - I checked the visEupload.php file properties and it has full control for system, me, and administrators, and users have read & execute, and read permissions.   I don't think that's the problem since table.php has the same permissions and I can access it...  Although, I'm not sure what differences are needed between a file accessed directly and a file accessed through submit/get.

Comment: what about the iusr account? iis doesn't run as a standard "user".

Comment: Should I add permissions on visEupload.php to give iusr permissions of full control then, you think?

Comment: I tried adding both iusr and iusr_something giving it full control and neither affected it.  I'm still getting 403_error.html.  I'm still not sure why it says the requested url is http://localhost:80/errorpages/403_error.html.  Could it be 403_error.html has access issues?

Comment: I don't see anything called errorpages/403_error.html where it's looking.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!  The problem was with the Session file I was referring to in visEupload.php.  It was missing it's error libraries, and that's what file it couldn't find.  When I commented out that reference, my added print statements showed up.  That was the custom error url it was complaining about.  Thanks!